# Updating an Application on a locked down user's PC

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, software-distribution

I am writing a Windows forms application to go between our other systems and our new software package that we are still setting up. I am doing an iterative development method because I am creating the tools as we find that we need them. My problem now is that when I publish a new change, we have to go to the workstations, log in as admin, and install this app. Being the process as it is, this just isn't feasible.

What other options do I for releasing this to the users? And how would I go about doing it?

I am using VS2008 and .NET 3.5

Comment: Is there a reason why you need admin rights for install (e.g. COM registration or installing stuff in the GAC etc)?

Comment: I remember seeing an error about GAC and authorized. I don't remember the exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use [ClickOnce deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Web Update Wizard](http://www.powerprogrammer.co.uk/)  Which installs a service (which runs with admin rights) when you first install your app.  Then when it updates, the service does the updating.